# Вызов глобальной функции

Tags: c++

Сразу скажу, что пишу не на обычном C++, а под микроконтроллер AVR, но я думаю, что в этом плане никаких отличий нет.
Есть файл `main.cpp`, в нём функция `void FOO(char bar, char baz)`, которую нужно вызвать из класса `BAT`. Функция `FOO` не находится ни в каком классе, а функция, из которой её нужно вызвать - в классе `BAT`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пока что из вашей постановки вопроса не ясно, в чем проблема. Как вызвать функцию? Просто взять и вызвать. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А где класс `BAT` находится? В любом случае в месте вызова функция должна быть видима, т.е. надо либо сделать соответствующий заголовочный файл, либо добавить предварительное объявление функции. Типа:

```
void FOO(char, char);
```

После этого вызвать как любую другую свободную функцию. Например:

```
FOO('1', 'a');
```

Если вдруг в классе есть уже функция-член `FOO`, то чтобы вызвать глобальную нужно указать область видимости:

```
::FOO('1', 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, методов в с++ нет. Во вторых, "методы", которые не принадлежат классу, называются просто функциями.

Самый простой способ решить задачу - это в файле с классом BAT сделать forward declaration - то есть, просто добавить строку с именем функции и типами (как обычно пишут в h файлах).

Более правильный способ состоит в том, что бы создать отдельные cpp/h файлы и перенести функции туда. А сам h файл добавить в оба нуждающихся файла (main и BAT).